# reactjs map with correct indexing after delete

Tags: reactjs, object

I have the following components

```
MainObject.map(
              (object, key) =>
                object.currentItemStatus === "DELETE" ? (
                  ""
                ) : (
                  <CustomComponent
                    key={key}
                    identifyNumber={key}

                  />
                )
            )
```

I am mapping it so it will be displayed multiple times. When a component has a property "DELETE" on it I will now show it. Its working properly but I have a question, is there a way to make the property "key" when I am storing in "identifyNumber" to be numbering correctly?

Because for example I have 3 objects in my "MainObject" and the 2nd object is deleted or mark as DELETE. The key variable will still continue to count up to 3 item(0,1,2) instead of 2 since there is a item that mark as delete. Is there way to do that?

Comment: Note I am using "identifyNumber" to number my components, to distinguish them from one another.

Comment: Please add sample data and your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Providing index is not correct as key. You will have issues while rerendering. Key for one object should be unique. Try using some property from object.

https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using **filter** before map could help:

```
MainObject
  .filter(object => object.currentItemStatus !== "DELETE")
  .map((object, key) => (
    <CustomComponent
      key={key}
      identifyNumber={key}
    />
  ))
```